# $\int_b^\infty f(t)\,dt$ is finite and $f$ is continous. $f$ is also non-negative on $[b, \infty]$ and $b > 0$...

Tags: calculus

$\int_b^\infty f(t)\,dt$ is finite and $f$ is continous. $f$ is also non-negative on $[b, \infty]$ and $b > 0$. The question is: is $f$ necessarily a monotonic decreasing function from some point $c > b$ towards? 
I was thinking of the function $\dfrac{(\sin e^x)^2}{e^x}$ that disproves it by looking at its graph, but I have no idea how to compute the integral of this function.

Is there a more elegant solution for this question?

Comment: You don't have to compute the integral, you just need to show the integral is finite. Hint: $|\sin|\le1$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to calculate the integral, only show that it is finite. As such, you can note that your function is less than or equal to $e^{-x}$ for all $x\geq b$, and therefore the integral is smaller than $e^{-b}$.

Comment: But I can't use this without assuming what I want to prove...

Comment: Nevermind I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary:  Suppose $g$ is everywhere non-negative, $g=0$ everywhere except in the interval $\left[1-\frac 1 2, 1+\frac 1 2\right]$ and $g>0$ in that interval.  That implies $g(1/2) = g(3/2) = 0$.  Suppose further that
$$
\int_{1-\frac 1 2}^{1+\frac 1 2} g(x)\,dx = 1.
$$
Then let
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n} g(x-n).
$$
Then $f$ is non-negative everywhere and is $0$ every half-integer, and
$$
\int_{1/1}^\infty f(x)\,dx = 2.
$$
But $f$ is not everywhere decreasing, even weakly (i.e. non-increasing) on any interval of the form $[c,\infty)$.